OCaml error during after build when accepting command line input
I'm currently trying to learn OCaml via the "Real World OCaml: Functional Programming for the Masses" textbook. I've reached the point of trying to build my first executable after playing inside utop, but the program keeps crashing in the following manner. The code itself is the exact same from the book:
open Base 
open Stdio

let rec read_and_accumulate accum =
  let line = In_channel.input_line In_channel.stdin in
  match line with
  | None -> accum
  | Some x -> read_and_accumulate (accum +. Float.of_string x)

let () = 
  printf "Total: %F\n" (read_and_accumulate 0.)

And the error log after trying to build it with dune and running gives
Fatal error: exception Invalid_argument("Float.of_string ")
Raised at Stdlib.invalid_arg in file "stdlib.ml", line 30, characters 20-45
Called from Dune__exe__Main.read_and_accumulate in file "bin/main.ml", line 8, characters 44-61
Called from Dune__exe__Main in file "bin/main.ml", line 11, characters 23-47

I'll admit that I'm not too sure why Float.of_string seems to be the cause of the problem here, as it works just fine inside utop when I test it.
I should add that I'm running OCaml version 4.13.1 on Debian and that both Base and Stdio are installed. I can also add the screenshot below for clarification:


What happens if you use (Float.of_string x) instead of Float.of_string x?

@mkrieger1 Changing the line to Some x -> read_and_accumulate (accum +. (Float.of_string x)) doesn't change the result, sadly. Running dune build, dune exec sum and throwing some numbers produces the same error log.

It likely means that whatever you're reading in from the command line isn't valid for Float.of_string.

Please post a sample run as text. The only likely explanation is that you're providing something that can't be converted to a float. Given what you've shown us I cvan only guess that you're providing a blank line rather than just an EOF.

You probably need to trim the line, to remove the newline character, which prevents the string from being parsed as a float.

Are you learning OCaml, or learning to program? Suggest you work on making sure your code handles things like exceptions from Float.of_string usefully rather than letting them end execution. The only exceptions that should do that are things you genuinely can't handle.

As you've noted, the issue is with the input you provided. Rather than providing an EOF (end-of-file) signal, you've entered a blank line. We can readily see that this causes an exception.
# In_channel.(input_line stdin);;

- : string option = Some ""
# Float.of_string "";;
Exception: Failure "float_of_string".

The basic solution is very simple: press Ctrl-D to send the EOF signal. However, we can look at alternate ways to handle this exception which may be instructive.
Note: only standard library modules and functions used in the following.
You can handle the exception and use that to terminate the recursion.
let rec read_and_accumulate accum =
  let line = In_channel.input_line In_channel.stdin in
  match line with
  | None -> accum
  | Some x -> 
      (try
         read_and_accumulate (accum +. Float.of_string x)
       with
       | Failure _ -> accum)

You could also skip that "faulty" input.
let rec read_and_accumulate accum =
  let line = In_channel.input_line In_channel.stdin in
  match line with
  | None -> accum
  | Some x -> 
      (try
         read_and_accumulate (accum +. Float.of_string x)
       with
       | Failure _ -> read_and_accumulate accum)

You might also extract the process of reading input and getting a sum of the float values:
let rec read_lines () =
  match In_channel.(input_line stdin) with
  | None -> []
  | Some line -> line :: read_lines ()

This function will read in a list of lines which we could then process using List module functions.
# read_lines ()
  |> List.filter_map 
       (fun line -> 
          try Some (Float.of_string line)
          with Failure _ -> None)
  |> List.fold_left (+.) 0.;;
5.0
7.1
8.42



7.0
2.0
- : float = 31.52

You might rightly say that generating a list isn't strictly required, and you'd be right, so OCaml provides a module for lazy sequences: Seq.
# let rec read_lines_seq () =
    match In_channel.(input_line stdin) with
    | None -> Seq.Nil
    | Some line -> Seq.Cons (line, read_lines_seq);;
val read_lines_seq : string Seq.t = <fun>
# read_lines_seq 
  |> Seq.filter_map 
       (fun line -> 
          try Some (Float.of_string line)
          with Failure _ -> None)
  |> Seq.fold_left (+.) 0.
;;
6
7
8
1.2
3.4
- : float = 25.5999999999999979


Thank you for this detailed answer. I have only recently gotten into some actual programming (having only done R for statistics classes and some Python) with a math background, not a CS one. I'm mostly doing it for the fun of learning, picking up some C, some OCaml, some Ada.

As mentioned in the comments, the correct way to end the program was via Ctrl-D instead of hitting Enter twice, my bad.
